# How to set a custom image and location for drag handles on table views

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, tableview

Is there a way to customize the location and image for the drag/drop handle in tableview in Xcode?I have a side nav (table view) that the user needs to be able to move things around on the table, so I put it in editing mode which automatically makes a button that is used to move the cells. But the button doesn't seem to be changeable.

I can not find anything online for this problem either. Placing an image over the drag handle breaks the functionality, so that work around didn't go well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should post some of your code, but I think you want to create buttons that will update the table without the drag and drop, is that it?

you can make the buttons reorder the array in the way you want and then:

```
   UIView.transition(with: tableView,
                      duration: 0.35,
                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: { self.tableView.reloadData() })
```

you can also use the drag options to use that as a more interactive way.

If it is something else, I would need more details